# How do I insert data into a SET column for a mysql database with jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem.
I have a database with table `accommodation` in it.

It has a column `attributes` with a datatype called `SET datatype`(mysql).

I want to set data with jdbc into this `attributes` column.

Can you please help how to do it.

Comment: What is the error? Please read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Please show us your code - anything done so far?

Comment: Note: I was asking "what is the error" because in the original title (before the edit) Kirti mentioned that there was "an error".

Comment: MySQL SET Reference for others who may stumble upon this question in a search: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query with the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) keyword.

EDIT: sorry, you are trying to insert. Example from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html):

```
INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('a,d'), ('d,a'), ('a,d,a'), ('a,d,d'), ('d,a,d');
```

EDIT: removed dead link to  http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/mysql/the-mysql-set-datatype

Comment: the table has columns with set  like attributes set("bath","gym","24 reception","internet")i have simple jdbc programme with connection,statements etc in it. i want to insert the data using statements into the database.i got error like data truncating in the column attributes as it contains set elements in it

Comment: What was the _Why you shouldn't use set_ link about before it went down? I fail to see any other articles online which put down SET. I'm a C++ developer and I've heard people *try* to say `std::set` shouldn't be used, but it's simply not true.

Comment: I seriously cannot remember, sorry.